# The electric field of a ring of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image: Physics for Scientists and Engineers 3rd Edition]

I'm studying ahead for my Electricity and Magnetism course for next quarter. I have a hard time approaching this course qualitatively, not quantitatively as a computer science major. I was wondering if there might be a different approach, less quantitative and more qualitative way of modelling this truth.

At the start of 25.4 my text book makes an assertion that the electric field vectors point away from the ring, increasing in length until reaching a maximum when |z| ≈ R, then begins to decreases. Then it tells me to stop for a minute to think about why this is true. I've been thinking about it for the better part of a day and I wanted to know, firstly, if I'm approaching what they said correctly. Secondly, and more importantly if there was a different more qualitative way to model this.

As z or R approaches 1, θ of the angle between r and z approaches 45°. At 45° my point charge for a disk of charge reaches a maximum. My math seems to work out but I don't know whether my thinking is on track and I'm sure there's a different more qualitative approach to this that is obscured to me.

[image: point charge 3D plot]

Comment: What do you mean by "my point charge for a disk of charge".  What is your figure supposed to represent?  And what is the formula that you have written?  It is *not* the field due to a ring of charge.  More importantly:  you should reason this out without doing any calculations.  The answer the book is looking for has to do with reasoning about the nature of fields due to charges, not math.

Comment: I've tried to reason this out without doing the math. My textbook focused exclusively on explaining this section with math and I think it intimidated me to be honest. I apologize if my post was not in congruence with the goals of this board. 1. By my point of charge I mean the point P in figure 26.14 on the page to the left. 2. The figure is meant to represent a ring of charge. 3. The formula represents the electric field of a point charge.

Comment: I've been able to reason conceptual questions in the book up to this point, getting the correct answers while staying away from the math up to this section. Again I apologize, I'm really just trying to build good fundamentals. Stackoverflow has been an immeasurable helpful tool in all my studies and I don't want to do anything to hurt any of these wonderful communities.

Comment: The kind of thinking that the book wants to encourage is the kind in the answer by @tmwilson26, or even the one by Spriko.  The one you chose is correct and well-presented, but it's more mathematical than physical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear to me what kind of answer you're looking for but this is how I would approach a qualitative justification for the result.

First, given the symmetry of the problem, for a point on the $z$ axis, the $z$ component of the electric field, due to each charge element, *add up* while the components parallel to the $x,y$ plane *cancel out*.

So, the electric field at any point on the $z$ axis has only a $z$ component.

Now, the *magnitude* of the electric field due to a charge element falls with the distance squared:

$$E \propto \frac{1}{r^2} = \frac{1}{R^2 + z^2}$$

But the $z$ component is *zero* in the plane of the ring ($z=0$) and gets *relatively* stronger with distance:

$$\frac{E_z}{E} = \frac{z}{r} = \frac{z}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}}$$

Thus

$$E_z \propto \frac{z}{r^{3/2}} = \frac{z}{(R^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}$$

So, there are two effects as $z$ increases from 0:

1. the increasing relative strength of the $z$ component of the
   electric field (due to a charge element)
2. the decreasing magnitude of the electric field

It follows that there must be a maximum in the $z$ component and it is reasonable to expect that the maximum is when $z$ becomes comparable with $R$.

To verify, we take the derivative of the $z$ component and find the value of $z$ for which it is zero:

$$\frac{d}{dz} \frac{z}{(R^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{(R^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} - 3\frac{z^2}{(R^2 + z^2)^{5/2}} = 0$$

The solutions are

$$z = \pm \frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense to me and is a wonderful explanation of what I was talking about but in particular it makes a connection with math to what they were showing me in figure 26.15 a & b. I will attempt to approach problems like this in the future. Proportionality is a concept that clearly hasn't been impressed upon me enough and I will strengthen my understanding of it going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too far on the qualitative side, but there are a few different scaling arguments to consider.

When $z \ll R$, you know that the $z$-component of the electric field should should increase linearly with $z$, and is 0 at $z=0$.  (This is because the $z$-component of the field scales as $\frac{z}{(z^2+R^2)^{3/2}}$, for small $z$, the $z$ in the denominator can be ignored)

When $z \gg R$, your ring of charge should look like a point charge, and the field should fall off to zero as $1/z^2$.

In between these two extremes, the field should have a maximum, and this will be when $z$ is on the same order as $R$.  Thats why it has the "approximately equal to" symbol, I think that it just wants you to think about the scaling arguments.

Answer (score 1):

For a conceptual answer, think about the electric field due to two equal positive point charges. If you are halfway in between them, their contributions cancel, and the net field is zero.

If you move perpendicular to the line that connects them, the field contributions will still mostly cancel, but some will point away, in the direction you moved. The field has increased.

If you keep moving, eventually the field will have to decrease back to zero just because the field contributions both go to zero. Somewhere along the way there was a maximum.

The ring of charge is the same thing, except the point charges are opposing $dq$ bits of the overall charge distribution.

Comment: Is this sort of what you mean? http://i.imgur.com/qrXUvJv.png I know this is true but I guess I wasn't making the this connection to earlier part of the chapter. Around point three in the middle is the maximum?

Comment: We generally frown upon actually answering questions like this one.   We prefer to guide the OP to figuring it out him or herself.

Comment: @jake Yes.  That model has the qualitative behavior that comes out in the math.  Now go do the math!

Answer (score 0):

For those looking into further insights on this example, Ramamurti Shankar from Yale went into the same example as my textbook. He goes on further by proving with the integral why the $\vec{E}$ for a annulus is not dependent on the distance. His use of symmetry is very helpful I found and did a better job connecting earlier concepts that were brought up than my text book did.

https://youtu.be/e9c5Wpu4WSI?t=31m54s